# How to insert a value at index for linked list? c++ Segmentation Fault error

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble finding what error I have in connecting my insert with in the linked list as I am getting a Segmentation Fault each time. Any suggestions on what I should focus on in order to find this problem will be appreciated.

```
bool LinkedList::InsertAtIndex(int value, int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    LinkedListNode* tmp = new LinkedListNode();

    tmp->data = value;

    tmp->next_node = NULL;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        tmp->next_node = head;
        head = tmp;

        return true;
    }
    LinkedListNode* head_ref = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
    {
        head_ref = head_ref->next_node;
        if (i == index - 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (head_ref == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    temp->next_node = head_ref->next_node;
    head_ref->next_node = temp;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there as many items in your LinkedList as the index you use to insert at?  Does inserting at 0 work correctly?

Comment: You may want to also check `head` and `temp` for `NULL`. Also check `head_ref` for `NULL` before `head_ref = head_ref->next_node;`

Comment: Focus on firing up the debugger and stepping through the function, watching for bad or NULL `next_node`s.

Comment: The `if (i == index - 1) break;` in the `for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)` has no effect since `i` will be at most `index - 2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple problems when the node is inserted after index 0. I re-wrote the code snippet and tried to explain those cases.

```
LinkedListNode* prev = head; // Locate node previous to insertion point
for (int i = 0; prev != NULL && i < index; i++)
{
    // Use prev != NULL to make sure the list isn't shorter than the
    // index.

    // Use i < index to check all of 0...index-1 to get insertion 
    // at last index right. For example, in list a,b,c insert d at
    // position 3 (zero-based counting)

    if (i + 1 == index) // First, check to see whether i meets the 
    {                   // index criteria. If yes, break out. prev
        break;          // is set to the right value.
    }
    prev = prev->next_node; // Advance prev to the next node to check
}                           // the next index value.
```